# How did Newton find derivative of basic functions before formulating systematic Calculus?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, math-history

I think I read somewhere that Newton tried to find derivatives of basic functions like $x^2$ before formulating systematic calculus; how did/would he do it?

Comment: With a straightedge and some quality graph paper maybe?

Comment: It seems likely that finding derivatives of a few functions was _part of the process_ by which Newton developed his version of the calculus. I wonder how well we can ever know these details, however, since Newton was very secretive about this work for a long time.

Comment: Relevant books: *Analysis by Its History* and *e: The Story of a Number*.

Comment: The tangents and areas of $x^n$ _(and lots of other functions)_ were known long before Newton/Liebnitz _([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_quadrature_formula#History))_.  They were just the first ones to put all the pieces together.

Comment: more often than not in mathematics we have some basic examples to work with before developing a general theory. the examples motivate the theory.

Answer (score 45):

The earliest formulations of something that looks like calculus were not in terms of *functions* but of *curves* given by algebraic relations. So if we have
$$ y=x^2 $$
and $(y+p,x+q)$ is another point on the curve, we would also have
$$ (y+p) = (x+q)^2 $$
and if we multiply these equations out and subtract we get
$$ p = 2qx + q^2 $$

Now what happens in the earliest sources is that it is simply *postulated*, without any backing by theoretical definitions or limits that **when $p$ and $q$ are small, we can remove their higher powers**, so ignoring the $q^2$ term yields us
$$ p = 2qx \qquad\text{or, in other words,}\qquad p:q = 2x:1 $$
which can be used to draw a tangent.

The justification for this procedure was initially just that it worked in practice, but the unexplained ignoring of terms like $q^2$ drew quite a lot of contemporary criticism.

This was in the generation before Newton (chiefly Fermat and Descartes). They could produce painstaking *geometric* proofs in the Euclidean tradition (which was the gold standard for proofs in those days) that *for each of the actual curves they considered* what came out of this procedure was the right result -- but they didn't have the definitions and machinery to explain or prove rigorously why the procedure *always* works.

Newton brought in the new idea of a quantity $x$ that varied with *time* and its time rate of change $\dot x$, but he was still building on the "ignore higher powers of the increments" method. But he did it masterfully and was able to get more out of it than his predecessors did.

Comment: It never crossed them to express $p$ in terms of $q$?

Comment: @Ovi: It was a bit simplified; I have edited to improve. The workers _before_ Newton thought of curves. Newton thought of things being functions of _time_. Only later did a general concept of function materialize.

Comment: I want to know what those verifying geometric proofs are. This approach still feels like calculus and my impression is that for some curves there are decidedly "non-calculus" proofs.

Comment: @abnry There is another VERY tedious geometrical historic approach to finding tangent lines and it's somewhere in an answer to one of my questions. I'll see if I can find it

Comment: Wasn't the mathematical formalism we know of nowadays introduced at a much much later point in time than Newton's era? I know that during the middle ages (and of course some later centuries) people expressed all their ideas, formulas even with long long texts, more or less prosa like / (accurate!). I have to admit I haven't read/looked into any papers of Newton. (Going to do that as soon as possible!)

Comment: @Imago: Modern algebraic notation was essentially complete by the time of Descartes (who introduced the convention of using letters at the end of the alphabet for unknowns and letters at the beginning of the alphabet for known constants). Descartes was one of the _forerunners_ of Newton.

Comment: Oh ok, this definitely changes a lot. According to wikipedia Descatzes did kinda of "invent" algebra or at least bring a proper notation for algebra/geometry in mathematics. And was kind of a role model / great/postive influence for Newton.

Answer (score 16):

Some of these were likely found through a combination of intuition and geometric reasoning.

Consider $y = x^2$. Notice that the square of side length $x$ has area $y$. Suppose that we change the side length by $dx$. Then what is the change in the area of the rectangle $dy$?

[image]

I apologize for the crudely drawn picture, but notice that the change in area that we get is,

$$dy = xdx+xdx+(dx)^2 = 2xdx+(dx)^2 \approx 2xdx$$

for small enough $dx$ (i.e. the little black square is insignificantly small). And thus,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2xdx}{dx} = 2x.$$

Similar reasoning can be used to show that $\frac{d}{dx} (x^3) = 3x^2$ by considering the change in volume of a cube.

EDIT: Figured it was worth mentioned that this same square technique can be used to intuitively see why $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x) \cdot g(x)) = f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)$.

EDIT 2: After you have the product rule, it is easy to derive the power rule (over the natural numbers) using induction. The base case $\frac{d}{dx}(x^1) = 1$ is obvious. If we assume $\frac{d}{dx}(x^k) = kx^{k-1}$, then,
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^{k+1}) = \frac{d}{dx}(x^{k} \cdot x) = \frac{d}{dx}(x^{k})\cdot x + x^{k} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x)$$$$ = kx^{k-1}\cdot x+x^k\cdot 1 = kx^k+x^k = (k+1)x^k.$$

Comment: @ClementC.Thank you, I promise they look a lot nicer on paper :)

Comment: With regard to your first edit: How can the double-product term be explained away in $\mathrm{d} (f g)=\mathrm{d} f (g+\mathrm{d}g)+\mathrm{d}g(f+\mathrm{d}f)=\mathrm{d}f \cdot g+\mathrm{d}g \cdot f+2\mathrm{d}f \mathrm{d}g$ (hopefully it is clear where this comes from, otherwise let me know)? I would like to use it for high school-students; what would be a good, intuitive argument for why that term vanishes, and the other ones don't? Perhaps something about comparing the speeds at which they vanish?

Comment: @Lovsovs: I think anything other than "defining algebra that way gives us the results we want" or "let me introduce a more sophisticated mathematical object" is ultimately going to be a lie -- of particular note is that if $f$ and $g$ are *independent*, then we still have $\mathrm{d}(fg) = f \mathrm{d}g + g \mathrm{d}f$, but $\mathrm{d} f \mathrm{d} g$ does **not** vanish.

Comment: @Hurkyl Sure, but intuitions can still be very helpful. That sounds interesting; could you provide a resource about it (perhaps a link)? Thanks

Comment: @Lovsovs : In general, a product $du \cdot dv$ of two infinitesimals is considered to be essentially 0.

Comment: @Lovsovs Well, we want to see what happens when $dx \to 0$ so in the ratio $\frac{d(fg)}{dx}$, we have the term $2\frac{dfdg}{dx} = 2\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dg}{dx}dx$. Notice in the limit, each factor in the previous product is defined so $\lim_{dx \to 0} 2\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dg}{dx}dx = 2f'g' \cdot 0 = 0$. However, I'm not an expert in non-standard analysis so this type of argument may not exactly be rigorous.

Comment: -1 this is only speculation and not a serious answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here is some historical information cited from Oskar Beckers *[Grundlagen der Mathematik in geschichtlicher Entwicklung](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000BG8K5)* (say: *Foundations of mathematics in historical development*).

The first matured presentation of Newtons (1643 - 1727) *[method of fluxions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Fluxions)* which was his name of differential calculus dates from 1670/71. The title was *Methodus fluxionum et serierum infinitarum* and has been posthumously  published in 1736.

> Newton started to think about fluxions some years before. Here is a small excerpt from one of his early notes cited from O. Becker [ch. *Fluxionsmethode p.147]*.
>
> - **Newton: (from 23.11.1665)**
>
>   ...If two bodies $A$ and $B$ move uniformly, one of them from $A$ to $C,E$ and $G$, the other from $B$ to $D,F$ and $H$ along the same line, then the line segments $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$, $\overline{CE}$ and $\overline{DF}$, $\overline{EG}$ and $\overline{FH}$ behave in the same manner as their velocities $p$ and $q$ and, if they do not uniformly move, then the infinite small line segments behave in each momentum as their velocities in each momentum.
>
>   [image]
>
>   If  the body $A$ with velocity $p$ describes the infinite small distance $o$ in a momentum, then the body $B$ will describe in the same momentum with velocity $q$ the distance  $\frac{op}{q}$. Since $p:q=o:\frac{oq}{p}$. So, if the line segments already described within one momentum  are $x$ and $y$, the next will be $x+o$ and $y+\frac{oq}{p}$.
>
>   Now I'm allowed, if the equation of the line is represented by
>     \begin{align*}
>   rx+xx-yy=0
>   \end{align*}
>     to substitute $x+o$ and $y+\frac{oq}{p}$ for $x$ and $y$ in the equation. This is valid, since they both mean in the same way as $x$ and $y$ the travelled distance described by the bodies $A$ and $B$. We obtain:
>     \begin{align*}
>   rx+xo+xx+2xo+oo-yy-\frac{2qoy}{p}-\frac{qqoo}{pp}=0
>   \end{align*}
>     But, according to the assumption we have:
>     \begin{align*}
>   rx+xx-yy=0
>   \end{align*}
>     after subtraction:
>     \begin{align*}
>   ro+2xo+oo-\frac{2qoy}{p}-\frac{qqoo}{p}=0
>   \end{align*}
>     and after division by $o$:
>     \begin{align*}
>   r+2x+o-\frac{2qy}{p}-\frac{oqq}{p}=0
>   \end{align*}
>
>   Now, the terms which contain $o$ are infinitely smaller than the terms which do not contain $o$. So, after cancelling these terms we obtain:
>     \begin{align*}
>   r+2x-\frac{2qy}{p}=0\qquad\text{or}\qquad pr+2px=2qy
>   \end{align*}
>
>   ...

This is an early example how Newton treated problems of differentiation of functions like $y=x^2$.  It indicates the development of differential calculus was driven solely to solve physical problems and calculation with infinitesimals was reasoned by physical evidence.

According to O.Becker it was Newtons teacher *[Isaac Barrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Barrow)* who inspired him to develop these first ideas. On the other hand intensive studies indicate that especially Blaise Pascal inspired Leibniz in *his* development of differential calculus methods.

Answer (score 3):

Here was how for $f(x)=x^2$:

$$\frac{f(x+o)-f(x)}{o}=2x+o.$$
Now if $o$ gets small, the quotient gets close to $2x$, so Newton declared that when $o$ "gets to" 0, the quotient "gets to" $2x$.

Note, though, that in Newton's times there was no rigorous formulation of limits. So perhaps he was drawing conclusions somewhat from intuition and experimentation. But also keep in mind that intuition was where calculus stemmed from.

Answer (score -3):

Surely any child with an interest in numbers will notice that in a quadratic sequence like 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ..., the differences between successive terms form a linear sequence like 3, 5, 7, 9, ...? That doesn't need calculus; but someone with a sophisticated mathematical brain will start to recognise that there's a relationship between the function that generates the first sequence and the function that generates the second, and will develop such thinking to discover the principles of calculus.